# How to generate combinations two element of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I have an array() contains string F1, F2, F3, F4.........

```
<?php
  $facts= array("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4);
?>
```

How can I generate combinations two elements of that array.
The output can be like that:

F1.F2 
F1.F3 
F1.F4
F2.F3 
F2.F4 
F3.F4

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Solution**

```
$facts= array("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4");

$new_array = array();
foreach($facts as $key => $val){
    foreach($facts as $key2 => $val2){
        if($key2 <= $key) continue;
        $new_array[] = $val . '.' . $val2;
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => F1.F2
    [1] => F1.F3
    [2] => F1.F4
    [3] => F2.F3
    [4] => F2.F4
    [5] => F3.F4
)
```

Comment: Thanks, If I want to generate combinations of 1 to n elements of array() has n value.  how can I do? The output should be : "F1","F2","F3","F1.F2","F1.F3","F2.F3","F1.F2.F3"

Comment: @HàmLouis I think you should create another question for that.